# How to save the information from a dynimic table - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table with the following options:

```
 <select name="test" class="test" >
 <option value="clear"></option> 
 <option value="fiat">FIAT</option> 
 <option value="gm">GM</option>
 </select>
```

Then I have my .JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

// fiat
var fiat = [
    { field1: 'XXXXXXXXX', field2: 'XXXXXXXXXX', field3: 'XXXX', field4: 'xxxxxxxxx' },                                                                         
    { field1: '', field2: '', field3: 'xxxxx', field4: '' },
    { field1: '', field2: '', field3: 'xxxxxx', field4: '' }
    ];

//GM
var gm = [
    { field1: 'XXXXXXXXX', field2: 'XXXXXXXXXX', field3: 'XXXX', field4: 'xxxxxxxxx' },                                                                         
    { field1: '', field2: '', field3: 'xxxxx', field4: '' },
    { field1: '', field2: '', field3: 'xxxxxx', field4: '' }
    ];

     var dt = dynamicTable.config('data-table', 
                             ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4'], 
                             ['XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'], 
                             'There is no items here');
```

And my function to call:

```
$('.teste').change(function(e) {



/* */
        switch(this.value) {
        case "fiat": 
            dt.load(fiat); 
            break;
        case "gm": 
            dt.load(gm); 
            break;

                }

     }) 

 });
```

Of course when I press "submit" all table information chosen by the user won't be saved. 
So, I have a worlflow with different approvers on it and I would like that the next assigned were able to see that information that was chosen.

Is there any way to treat it with JS or am I dreaming?

PS: I can provide the code if you want.

Thanks :)

Comment: I not sure i understand the questions. When they select the make of car, you want to do something with the data for that make, do you want it to render in the page, or do you want to send it somewhere?

Comment: Sorry to take a long time to give a comment. My original idea does not make sense now.